# Ionic 3 add tabs at run time

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my application I am using 3 tabs, based on the Web service response I need to add or remove the current showing tabs at runtime. How to achieve this?

Comment: hope this helps: https://github.com/zyra/ionic2-super-tabs

Comment: Please refer this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-create-dynamic-tab-ionic/52043